# Texas Instruments USB2ANY HPA665

Tags: usb, usb-device, device

I encountered device made by Texas Instruments with label USB2ANY HPA665. It has LED, mini USB and FloppyDiskDrive-like ports.

I can't find any data-sheet, manual or resources what for and how to use this device. Looks like some kind of programmer/debugger? Can anyone help?

It has MSP430 microcontroller.

[image]

More pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D7Tw.jpg).

Comment: Just looking real fast this link http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa171/sloa171.pdf   Talks about it being used with some regulator evaluation software.  There may not be a stand alone manual for it.   It may just be something they used to give out with their eval kits.   Someone probably knows more about it here.

Comment: Does it have a LMH6657/LMH6658 IC on it?

Comment: no, it has TI's OAM A36X 2442AI (whatever it is, OAM sounds like operational ampli) [marked as U7 on the PCB]. It's hard to read what is U4 something like CVT TI K  19TD

Comment: There's a USB2ANY schematic at the end of this document. ftp://ftp.ti.com/pub/evm-pdk/TSC3060/TSC3060EVM_SBAU199.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The USB2Any is a USB to I2C platform that ships as part of several Texas Instruments evaluation kits (EVMs). It is not sold separately (hence no datasheet link available), but a substitute is [Aardvark](http://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark_i2cspi/) from Total Phase.

From one of the TI [E2E forum discussions](http://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/audio_amplifiers/f/6/p/207592/738785.aspx):

> The USB2ANY is only available with our EVMs.  If you order a LM48901 EVM, you will also receive a USB2ANY.  Aardvarks are available for purchase direct from Total Phase.

The USB2Any (and the Aardvark) is a really handy little device for debugging, configuring or controlling I2C devices from a PC using desktop software. Also the TI support team is very conversant with USB2Any.

Texas Instruments however is equally strongly supportive of I2C as an interconnect option: Note the EVMs they use it with, and posts on their E2E forums.